# Aptana studio 3 automatically includes html markup in rhtml files

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, aptana

I am learning ruby on rails using aptana studio 3. I created a view hello.rhtml. When I run the view and see the source I get to see js files automatically included. Even if my rhtml file is empty for eg

```
hello world
```

Without the html markup, and if I see the source, I can see the entire markup from html doctype etc already present. How do I stop the inclusion of automatic markup?

**EDIT:**

I create a hello.html.erb file. And put this code inside it

Hello

When I save and run the file, I get the output, but when I view source I get the following result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  
  <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1312799421" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1312799421" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1312799421" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1312799421" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1312799421" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1312799421" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="82LBP1pI5h0QzNW54PYSq/zdkS8kF4Z/nKSUHgKvv1g="/>
</head>
<body>

<html>
  <head><title>Hello</title></head>
  <body>
</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

As you see, I get html inside html and when in browser my title shows "Demo" instead of "Hello"

**Update:**

Here is the content of application layout. And I now understand that, the code is coming from this layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the best practice and what code should be present in application_layout.html.erb? I would like all my view files to have its own html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should have .html.erb extension not rhtml (That's a hang over from Rails 1.x).
Check out your application layout file. in the head section you'll see an entry for including JavaScript. Just comment that out and you js will not be included.

**UPDATE**
Have a close look at your application_layout.html.erb.

Comment: i have edited my question. Basically i am getting html markup with html markup within it. And if i dnt write a html code in my .html.erb file and run the code, i can still see the html code in my view source.

Comment: see my update. i now understand that the prob i had was cos of application_layout.html.erb...can you suggest best options for the same?..thanks

Comment: I removed all the other code from application_layout.html.erb and am using only <%= yeild %>. It works like how i want it to work...Hope this is a best pratice. Thanks

Comment: Hhhmmm! That doesn't sound right! I'll get back to you, but it'll take a while. I have to get up to speed with Rails 3.1

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an error, this is the way Rails works!**

Rails will generate views/layouts/application.html.erb for you, this is the basic template of the website.  With this template, you don't have to copy and paste the same html declarations on each page you make.

Rails uses a convention called MVC which stands for Model, View, Controller.  I suggest you read a bit more on how this works.  Basically, <%= yield %> will insert the contents of your view, but you must tell Rails which url points to which view.  Now you can have views/pages/home.html.erb, the contents of which might be..

```
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<p>Congratulations, you made a web page with Rails!</p>
```

And then in routes.rb

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'home' => 'pages#home'
end
```

When you go to http://localhost:3000/home, you should see your web page.  If you look at the source code, you will see the output generated by Rails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Home Page</h1>
  <p>Congratulations, you made a web page with Rails!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is definitely the proper way to use Rails.  The goal is DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).  Michael Hartl has a wonderful tutorial and introduction to using Ruby on Rails.  I would suggest anyone new to Ruby on Rails to start here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/.